# Why is dockerd running when service is stopped on Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk

Tags: azure

I deployed a VMSS with Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk to azure.

I am trying to upgrade the docker ee to preview, but noticed this odd behavior.

Right after deployment, connecting by Remote desktop, i found that

get-service shows that dockerd is registered as a service but not running.
get-process shows that a dockerd is running (so it must be started elsewhere).

I kill the process, upgrade docker ee to preview. I start the service and everything is working.

Then after a reboot, again a old dockerd is running (notice with get-process) and the new service is stopped (notice with get-service).

How do we remove the dockerd that Datacenter-Core-1709-with-Containers-smalldisk comes with ?

## update

I saw this in the service fabric release note:

```
Specify custom parameters that will be used when Service Fabric launches the Docker daemon.
```

So is this the problem? is service fabric extension lauching the deamon also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Service Fabric launches and manages the docker daemon on the machine. You can disable this by setting 'SkipDockerProcessManagement' under '[Hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings#section-name-hosting)' section to true. See [Customize Service Fabric cluster settings and Fabric Upgrade policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings)

In case you are looking to try [LCOW](https://github.com/linuxkit/lcow), Service Fabric currently does not support it.

Comment: Thanks. the link you provided did not have SkipDockerProcessManagement. but i will try

Comment: It is not documented as this is not a recommended setting for production and only intended to be used for debugging puposes in dev environment.